# How to install XDebug in Lampp to debug Magento?

Tags: magento2, debug, xdebug

I have installed xdebug from source in my system and add to my php.ini the following code at the end of the file:

**/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini**

```
[Xdebug]

zend_extension=”/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so”
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

I created a php file to see the state of the server:

**phpinfo.php**

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

After restart apache I have no information about xdebug running. I don't know what seems to be the error or what are missing.

I did: `/opt/lampp/bin $ phpenmod xdebug` And it created me a **xdebug.ini** in **/etc/php/7.0/mods-available** with

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so
```

Instead of compiling over source xdebug I downloaded the working builds from ActiveState (the makers of the Komodo IDE) provide their pre-compiled binaries of xdebug they use in their IDE.
Just go to their site:
http://aspn.activestate.com/ASPN/Downloads/Komodo/RemoteDebugging
The packages contain builds for all php versions.
I copied xdebug.so to **/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions** and changed my php.ini with the entry `zend_extension=”zend_extension=/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/xdebug.so”`
I changed also **xdebug.ini** with `zend_extension=/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/xdebug.so`
I restarted lampp and nothing seems to work for now.

When I run phpinfo.php with apache restarted I have no information about xdebug.

Comment: Just to make sure, have you checked to make sure that you `xdebug.so` is in the right place `/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so`? And when you run `php -v` in the command line, do you get the right version of php?

Comment: 1) first check /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so the file is available. 
2) enable using this command `php5enmod xdebug`
3) run php -v to check xdebug display xdebug.

Comment: Done Rama. My **php -v** gives `me PHP 7.0.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.7.0alpha1, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans` but when I start apache my **phpinfo.php** have no information about xdebug. I can't understand why.

Comment: can you provide php.ini file were you added the /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so.  i will check and  tell you :)

Comment: can you please update question and remove from ans. ans is used to provide the ans.

Comment: My php.ini is too large to put here :(

Answer (score 0):

***Configure Xdebug in Linux env(UBuntu)*** ***::***

1. Need to run ***phpinfo()*** to check ***xdebug*** is enable or not.

   IF not enable , need to run ***sudo apt-get install php-xdebug***
   Now, we have to restart our server to check xdebug is displaying after run
   ***phpinfo()*** function.
2. we can expect that xdebug is showing after run **phpinfo()**.

   Now, we have to make some configuration in ***php.ini*** file.
   try to add below piece of code at end of ***php.ini*** file

---

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_port="9000"
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
```

---

Again we have to restart server once

```
service apache2 restart //or /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Hope, we are using VS code(visual studio code)

Just need to install php xdebug in this IDE.
Reopen this IDE.

I think , everything will working fine.
NP: From my side , I have configure this & works like a charm.